# How to put an equatiomatic latex output into a xaringan slide?

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan, equatiomatic

I'm having trouble putting an equatiomatic formula output into a xaringan slide. For a standard rmd/quarto document, it's relatively simple. I follow the example on the package website and it works, but it doesn't seem to render in a xaringan document.

Take this very basic code for a xaringan slide:

````
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
---


```{r example-basic-preview, echo=FALSE}
library(equatiomatic)
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, mtcars)
extract_eq(mod1)
```
````

I can only get it to show the raw latex equation. I've tried numerous things like putting it on inline code, setting chunk option `results = 'asis'`, `cat()`ing it with $$ before and after but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xaringan is a bit picky about math expression](https://slides.yihui.org/xaringan/#16). Try in the following way,

````
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
---

```{r example-basic-preview, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(equatiomatic)

cat_eq <- function(...) cat("$$", extract_eq(...), "$$", sep = "")

mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, mtcars)
cat_eq(mod1)
```
````

---

[image: xaringan slide with equatiomatic equation]